# How to write unit tests for functions that read/write to a MySQL database?

Tags: javascript, python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have a simple application that reads and writes scores to a MySQL database using javascript and python/flask. I want to know how to best isolate the different units of the application for testing.

**JavaScript:**

- How would I mock this out and also would it require it's own specific tests in a JavaScript only testing suite?

  ```
  $scope.create_score = function () {
               console.log("logged");
               var scoreData = new scoreObj($scope.match_ID,$scope.Home_Score, $scope.Away_Score);
               if ($scope.Home_Score >= 0 && $scope.Away_Score >= 0) {
               $http(

                   {
                       method: 'POST',
                       url: "/api/v1/scores",
                       data: scoreData
                   }
               ).then(function successCallback(response) {
                       alert("Success");
                   }, function errorCallback(response) {
                       alert("Sorry, there was a problem!");
                   }
               )
                   } else {
                   alert("Sorry, score can not be negative!");
               }
           };
  ```

**Python:**

- These are the main functions I need to test.

  ```
  def execute_query_json(cursor, qry, cnx):
      print("Executing JSON query...")
      cursor.execute(qry, (request.json['Match_ID'],
                   request.json['Home_Score'],
                   request.json['Away_Score'],)
          )
      cnx.commit()

  def add_score():
      cnx = conn_db()
      cursor = cnx.cursor()
      print("Updating score")
      execute_query_json(cursor, "INSERT INTO scores (Match_ID, Home_Score, Away_Score) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)", cnx)
      return "ok"
  ```

**Tests:**

- How would I consolidate the different mocking methods (context managers/decorators) to be used in different tests?
- What are the use cases for the different mocking methods, or are they interchangeable?
- How would I create fake json/expected score data to be used for different mock objects?

  ```
  from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock
  from unittest.mock import Mock
  import unittest

  from source.src import scores
  from source.src.scores import add_score
  import source


  @patch('source.src.scores.request')
  def test_add_scores(self):
      columns = ["Match_ID", "Home_Score", "Away_Score"]
      values = [1, 1, 1]

      expected_score = {columns[i]: values[i] for i in range(len(columns))}
      json = {columns[i]:values[i] for i in range(len(columns)-1)}

      with patch('source.src.scores.mysql.connector') as patch_connector:
          self.assertIs(scores.mysql.connector, patch_connector)

          cursor = Mock()
          cursor.fetchone.return_value = values
          cursor.column_names = columns
          connect = Mock()
          connect.cursor.return_value = cursor
          patch_connector.connect.return_value = connect

          new_score = add_score()

          assert patch_connector.connect.called
          assert connect.cursor.called
          assert connect.commit.called
          assert cursor.fetchone.called
          self.assertEqual(cursor.execute.call_count, 2)
          self.assertDictEqual(expected_score, new_score)


  if __name__ == '__main__':
      test_add_scores()
  ```

Thanks so much guys, really boggling me how to test this.

Comment: Those assert statements should be `unittest.assertTrue()` or otherwise. [See the doc here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html)